# How do I transfer post requests to a different port with nginx?

Tags: http, nginx, post, https, production

I want to transfer all post requests to port 5000 as that's where my express server is running.
This is my nginx config at the moment:

```
server {
    if ($host = www.website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name www.website.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;


}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.website.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # manag$
```

I know that I should have probably thought about it before writing the code and make all post requests to /api and then redirect it from the config. But I haven't, and I don't want to change the code if that's node necessary.

How can I recognize if a request is a post request and transfer it to port 5000?

Also, in what language is this config file written in? it looks like js but it isn't really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better change your code, but as a quick and dirty hack you can try

```
server {
    ...
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        rewrite ^ /api$request_uri last;
    }
    location / {
        # your default location config here
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    }
}
```

NGINX config is not a programming language, it uses its own syntax and is rather declarative than imperative, changing the order of nginx directives (except of those from [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)) usually make no difference.

Comment: Thanks, and is there a specific reason that you have suggested I better change the code?

Comment: Just a design considerations. And this workaround would make almost impossible to add any other web app to your domain (if suddenly you need it in future).